# Retrieving the value of specific attribute using E Tree

Tags: python, xml, python-2.7

I have an XML document through which I want ti retrieve the value of specific attribute using e tree.
Below is the document-snippet I have:

```
-<orcid-message>
    <message-version>1.2</message-version>
  -<orcid-profile type="user">
    -<orcid-identifier>
        <uri>http://orcid.org/0000-0001-5105-9000</uri>
        <path>0000-0001-5105-9000</path>
```

I want to retrieve the value of only 'path'
I have tried so far:

```
tree = ET.parse(file)
root = tree.getroot()
for element in root:
    for all_tags in element.findall('.//'):
         if all_tags.text:
             print all_tags.text, '|', all_tags.tail
```

What should I do to only get the value of 'path'

Comment: Have you tried Element.get?
e.g. `Element.get('path')`

Comment: I impoted Element from e tree: 
from xml.etree.ElementTree import Element, SubElement, Comment
path = SubElement.get('path')
path = Element.get('path')
print(path)

But, this is not working.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Element class' [find](https://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#xml.etree.ElementTree.Element.find) method with the path to the element you wish to pick out, for example:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

tree = ET.parse("filename")
root = tree.getroot()
path = root.find("orcid-profile/orcid-identifier/path")
print(path.text)
```

Comment: I tried the code, but i get this error: AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text'

Comment: That would suggest the argument to root.find is incorrect - is the path to "path" the same in your full xml file the same as it is in the snippet in your question?

Comment: Yes, it is the same.